# Is There A Java Street Address Type?

Tags: java

I'm writing an application that stores people's street addresses.

I'm aware that addresses can be complicated (especially in parsing user input) so I'm concerned writing a simplistic class myself might cause me issues I have to fix later.

Is there a decent model in the JDK or an external library that I could utilise instead?

Comment: No! In JDK there are no Address Type, you have to create your own Model

Comment: No; [some reasons why not](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/). (A general address type would be too basic for specific cases; or too specific/detailed for use in basic cases).

Comment: What is this? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/PostalAddress.html

Answer (score 1):

No.  Java does not provide such modelling out of the box.  No language does.  If anything, stuff like that is implemented in a way of libraries or frameworks.

If you need to support international addresses, then I recommend looking at the field types and length from FedEx and/or UPS, because if you will model based on what you know from your country then you are bound to make many changes in the future.

Comment: Thats why I asked in the question about an external library